# Is it possible to customize the font of a Tool tip text in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In an eclipse application, I am using a dialog where different UI controls used such as Buttons, Labels, Combo boxes, TreeViewer, etc. For some UI controls, the tool tip is enabled. My requirement is to change the font characteristic (Bold & Italic) of the tool tip text.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Currently in Eclipse, you may not be able to change the font, color of the tooltip. We simply write `.setToolTipText(...)`. However, you can get some idea from the following link to build fancy tooltip.

https://dentrassi.de/2011/02/21/fancy-tooltips-in-eclipse/

I would suggest you to go for Eclipse Info Popup, you can do all kinds of customization. You can find below the link.

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073187/creation-of-infopopup-in-eclipse.html

Info popups appear as Javadocs in Eclipse.